# How to determine if an arbitrary text is a valid SQL Server schema’s name, and how to escape it for a T-SQL script?

Tags: .net, t-sql

I need to create a SQL Server object using T-SQL script. The object needs to be created at a schema provided at runtime.

I can’t use parameters for this kind of script though, so I have to construct the schema’s name prefix on the fly with correct escaping and then inject it into a template (if I’m going to use a template).

My concern is to open the door for any other kind of script injection.

I need to do this programmatically, and the platform is .NET.

Following a sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE [xpto].[Account] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [Account.PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY,
    [MemberId] INT CONSTRAINT [Account.MemberForeignKey] 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [xpto].[Member] ([Id]),
    [SomeField] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [AnotherField] INT
);
```

Comment: [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)?

Comment: Is it a standalone object like a lonely table, or do you need to be concerned about foreign key references, constraints, ...?

Comment: Note that using a template is very tempting because the only thing that changes in the entire script is the schema’s name.

Comment: @HABO: I do have to be concerned with foreign key references; I've just added a sample script.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I think that is exactly what I was looking for. You should post the comment as an answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://garywoodfine.com/check-if-schema-exists-in-sql-server-database/) help? It's one of the top results from Google for `t sql schema exists`.

Comment: @HABO: I’m not particularly worried about the existence, or about the creation, of the schema in this question. Thanks anyway.